# Render KML and image overlay on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, kml

I have the following simple kml which references an image file that I would like to overlay on a map view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
 <Document>
 <name>Map Overlay</name><open>0</open>
 <GroundOverlay>
 <Icon>earthdata.png</Icon>
 <LatLonBox>
 <north>80.0</north><south>-80.0</south><east>180.0</east><west>-180.0</west>
 </LatLonBox>
 </GroundOverlay>
 <ScreenOverlay>
 <name>Colormap</name>
 <Icon>
 <href>icon.png</href>
 </Icon>
 <overlayXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
 <screenXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
 <size x="-1" y="-1" xunits="fraction"  yunits="fraction"/>
 </ScreenOverlay>
 </Document>
 </kml>
```

Can anyone let me know how I can render this image view on an iPhone similar to how this file is displayed on google earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your KML into IOS Google Earth

1) Go to Google Maps http://maps.google.com/

2) Choose "My Maps"

2) Choose "make a new map"

3) Click on "import".

4) Choose the kml/kmz file you wish to add.

5) In the iphone/ipad Google Earth Application choose "Layers"

6) Choose "My Maps".

Your imported kml/kmz data will now show in the IOS application just like in the full Google Earth Client.

Comment: Just to note, if you want an image overlay to be relative then you will need to package the KML file and the 'earthdata.png' image together as a KMZ archive for it to work. Otherwise you would need to upload the image onto a server and change the path to an absolute on in the kml...